# Python: Dynamically raise an exception on import when missing dependency

Tags: python, import

I have a package with a structure like this:

```
foo/
  __init__.py
  bar1.py
  bar2.py
```

`bar1` and `bar2` have classes `Bar1` and `Bar2`. I have inserted in `__init__.py` the import to the classes in order to allow

```python
from foo import Bar1
```

instead of writing

```python
from foo.bar1 import Bar1
```

Ok, this is working fine, now comes the tricky part.

`bar1` and `bar2` can raise the exception `MissingDependency` when imported with some dependency missing

So my `__init__.py` is implemented like this

```python
try:
    from .bar1 import Bar1
except MissingDependency:
    pass

try:
    from .bar2 import Bar2
except MissingDependency:
    pass
```

That means that the import of `foo` works but it does not import `Bar1` or `Bar2`

```python
import foo
```

Now, what I would like to do is to raise `MissingDependency` when you try to import Bar1 and it fails.

Currently what happens is

```python
from foo import Bar1
... 
ImportError: cannot import name Bar1
```

I want it to raise `MissingDependency`

```python
from foo import Bar1
... 
MissingDependency: "Cannot import Bar1"
```

EDIT: I corrected some mistakes with packages names

Comment: Just catch an `ImportError` and raise your own exception in `except` block?

Comment: So to be clear, you want to raise no exception on `import package`? What about `from package import *`?

Comment: I want to be able to do `import foo`. If I catch `ImportError` and raise my own exceptions it will fail also `import foo`. I want it to fail only on `from foo import Bar1`

Comment: @svituz: Python implements `from foo import Bar1` as (roughly) `import foo; Bar1=foo.Bar1; del foo`.  You could replace the `foo` module with an object that overrides `__getattr__`, I suppose, but I think Python might still catch your custom exception and reraise it as an `ImportError`.

Comment: I've been looking for this with a slightly different use case: I want to allow `from foo import Bar2`, but to raise an exception for `from foo import Bar1`, to make the missing dependency explicit to users (rather than `Bar1` simply not being importable from `foo`).

Answer (score 2):

For the ones interested, I've found a solution implementing the [PEP0302](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/#specification-part-1-the-importer-protocol)

Basically I wrote a finder and loader class and added it to sys.meta_path

```python
import sys
import imp  

class MyLoader(object):
    def find_module(self, name, path=None):
        try:
            return imp.find_module(name, path)
        except ImportError as ie:
            if name == 'foo.Bar1':
                raise MissingDependency()
            raise ie

    def load_module(self, name):
        return imp.load_module(name)

try:
    from .bar1 import Bar1
except:
    pass

try:
    from .bar2 import Bar2
except:
    pass

sys.meta_path = [MyLoader()]
```

Answer (score -1):

it is probably not what are you looking for... But you want to change default mechanism of handling import.

```
try:
  from package import Mod1
except ImportError:
  raise MissingDependency
```